# Build url string using C#

Tags: c#, json

I've been trying to build the request url for my json request but been getting a 404 error. This is the code I put together after reading some threads on it. Can anyone help?

```
var apiKey = "123456";
var Query = "some search";
var Location = "San Jose, CA";
var Sort = "1";
var SearchRadius = "100";

var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

values["k"] = apiKey;
values["q"] = Query;
values["l"] = Location;
values["sort"] = Sort;
values["radius"] = SearchRadius;

string url = "http://api.website.com/api" + values.toString();
```

This is where I am getting the error. After passing the url on client.DownloadString()

```
var client = new WebClient();
var json = client.DownloadString(url);
var search = Json.Decode(json);
```

Comment: A JSON request? You are not even close to JSON with the code shown in your question. What does the server expects? What's the correct endpoint to be called?

Comment: **`UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http://api.website.com/api");
    builder.Query = values.ToString();
    var url = builder.ToString();`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [UriBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx). It will ensure the resulting URI is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is building an invalid URL:

```
http://api.website.com/apik=123456&q=some+search&l=San+Jose%2c+CA&sort=1&radius=100
```

Note the `/apik=123456` portion.

```
var apiKey = "123456";
var Query = "some search";
var Location = "San Jose, CA";
var Sort = "1";
var SearchRadius = "100";

// Build a List of the querystring parameters (this could optionally also have a .ToLookup(qs => qs.key, qs => qs.value) call)
var querystringParams = new [] {
  new { key = "k", value = apiKey },
  new { key = "q", value = Query },
  new { key = "l", value = Location },
  new { key="sort", value = Sort },
  new { key = "radius", value = SearchRadius }
};

// format each querystring parameter, and ensure its value is encoded
var encodedQueryStringParams = querystringParams.Select (p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.value)));

// Construct a strongly-typed Uri, with the querystring parameters appended
var url = new UriBuilder("http://api.website.com/api");
url.Query = string.Join("&", encodedQueryStringParams);
```

This approach will build a valid, strongly-typed Uri instance with UrlEncoded querystring parameters.  It can easily be rolled into a helper method if you need to use it in more than one location.

Comment: But how is this related to a JSON request which is what the OP seems to be asking about? So either he doesn't know what JSON is or you didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - because it is 404ing on the address.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm going with the former.

Comment: @KarlAnderson, and what does this has to do with JSON?

Comment: @asawyer, yeah me too.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - it doesn't, because I think the OP wants to receive JSON, not send it. Don't you think this line `var json = client.DownloadString(url);` indicates that?

Comment: @KarlAnderson, just read at his question title: `Build a Json Request Url Using C#`. That doesn't quite seem to mean receiving JSON. Or am I crazy?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - is it possible his question title is wrong? Not trying to be a jerk here, but just saying the code and the title do not match.

Comment: @KarlAnderson, oh, yeah, pretty many things are possible :-) I am just basing my comments on facts that I am seeing. If we assume that questions are all wrong, then, well, though to answer here :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - :-) LOL

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - understood, I will gladly delete my answer if the OP states he is looking to send JSON and then receive JSON back.

Comment: @alvin - my answer might be a bit overkill for your specific question, but it's a good way to safely build a valid URL with a varying number of parameters (it's smarter/more flexible than string concatenation)